# How to secure production deployment credentials with GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm currently setting up a development workflow with a protected production branch in GitLab with the hopes of using GitLab CI to handle the build & deploy steps.

How can I protect my production SSL credentials from other developers on the project? I realize GitLab CI has secret variables, but there doesn't seem to be a way to prevent a developer from dumping these using a test build on another branch of the project.

Am I missing something, or is there different way to lock down access to the production server?

Comment: What do you mean by "SSL credentials"?

Comment: Either username/password or a key. Just looking for some sort of locked down authentication method to be used by the runner for our production branch that cannot be accessed via tests/builds on other branches.

Comment: In place of "SSL creditials" imagine "secrets" what could be anything like passwords, SSH keys or API keys.

Comment: The issue is discussed [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/17633) and in other issues linked there.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a separate project with the deployment script that is not accessible by the developers you mention. Here yo can use the variables for storing the credentials. The first project can trigger the deployment project to when it's build stage succeeds.